# Example of a non-linear, non-continuous mapping from $\mathbb R$ onto $\mathbb R$ whose graph is closed

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis

Give an example of a non-linear mapping from $\mathbb R$ onto $\mathbb R$ whose graph is closed although it is not continuous.

Comment: See also [A function is continuous if its graph is closed](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/90665/a-function-is-continuous-if-its-graph-is-closed)